# RHEL 7.4 - moreutils dependency on perl IPC::Run

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I am trying to install `moreutils` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4, but it is complaining about a dependency on `perl(IPC::Run)`. Here is the command I'm running and the error message I am receiving:

```
# /bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install moreutils
Error: Package: moreutils-0.49-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(IPC::Run)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've tried searching for the package `perl-IPC-Run` but it does not seem to be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out `Perl-IPC-Run` is in the `rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` repository which had not been enabled.

These are the steps I took to fix the issue:

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
Repository 'rhel-7-server-optional-rpms' is enabled for this system.
# yum search Perl-IPC-Run
...
perl-IPC-Run.noarch : Perl module for interacting with child processes
```

Now the `Perl-IPC-Run` package is available and `moreutils` installs without an error.

Comment: For centOS 8 the required package is in powertools: `dnf config-manager --enable powertools`

Answer (score -1):

I have downloaded perl-IPC-Run-0.84-2.el6.rfx.noarch 
and issue was fixed 
http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-IPC-Run